# How to keep websocket open while redirecting to external link in ionic app?

Tags: android, websocket, ionic-framework, tornado

I have an ionic app in the client side and am using Tornado server on the backend for websocket connections.

I need to integrate payment gateway in my app. Once the user selects the desired purchase and clicks on a 'buy' button, I initialise the websocket.

The user is redirected to the payment gateway page, within the webview itself, however during this process, the websocket connection is being closed.

How do I keep this connection open?

This is my server side code:

```
# global variable that stores all clients
websockets = {}


# billing socket initiation handler
class BillingHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

  def open(self):

    logger.info("opening websocket connection: %s" %self.request)

  def on_closed(self):      

    logger.info("closing websocket connection")

  def on_message(self, message):      

    logger.info("message received: %s" %message)
    logger.info(self)

    # store client
    websockets[message] = self
    logger.info("websockets: %s" %websockets)

    resp_data = {"resp": "Received from client: {0}".format(message)}
    self.write_message(resp_data)

  def get(self):

    self.write('Hello from tornado')


# billing sockets request handler
class BillingRequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

  def post(self):

    # fetch token
    token = self.get_argument('token', None)

    # check for token
    if not token:

      logger.error("Token not presnet in BillingRequestHandler request")      
      self.set_status(400)
      return

    else:

      # get client from global variable websockets
      try:

        client = websockets[token]

      except:

        logger.error("Client not found for token in BillingRequestHandler: %s" %token)
        self.set_status(400)
        return

      else:

        print "client: %s" %client 
        print websockets

        resp_data = {"redirect" : True}
        client.write_message(resp_data)

        self.set_status(202)
        #client.close()

    #websockets = []


def main():

  parse_command_line()

  # define django wsgi application
  wsgi_app = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(
    django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler())

  # define all urls to be served by tornado applicatioon
  tornado_app = tornado.web.Application(
    [     

      # mobile app billing urls
      ("/api/mobile/open_billing_socket/", BillingHandler),
      ("/api/mobile/payu_response/", BillingRequestHandler),

      # pass rest of the urls to django wsgi app  
      ('.*', tornado.web.FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=wsgi_app)),

    ])

  # start tornado server
  server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado_app)
  server.listen(options.port)

  tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

This is my frontend code:

```
 // This function is called when user clicks the buy button:
 userService.generatePaymentData(pack_data)
      .then(function(result){

        // on successful generation of payment data, populate payu_form data 
        // then execute form submit to PayU to open payment gateway page

        if (result!==false && result.hasOwnProperty("txnid")){

            // Here the form values are populated
            // set form values to be POSTed to payu server
            ............................................                                

            var payu_form_data = {

            };

            // submit payu form
            // button with this id is clicked, that submits the form
            // and redirects webview to payment gateway page
            document.getElementById("id_payu_submit_button").click();

            // initiate websocket
            // this websocket closes when webciew is redirected to payment gateway page
            var socket = DOMAIN.socket + API_URLS.billingInitiationSocket;
            var connection = new WebSocket(socket);

            // When the connection is open, send some data to the server
            connection.onopen = function () {
              // Send the message 'Ping' to the server
              connection.send(userService.userSession.user_data.token); 
            };

            // Log errors
            connection.onerror = function (error) {
              console.log("Error in initiating billing socket: " + error);
            };

            // Log messages from the server
            connection.onmessage = function (e) {

              console.log('Server: ' + e.data);              
              var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
              console.log("Websocket received data: " + JSON.stringify(data));

              if (data.hasOwnProperty("redirect") && data.redirect===true){
                $state.go("app.home");
                alert("Something happened!");
              }

            };

});
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Hi, I used a really dirty hack, I had to use an i-frame within html, this way the page isn't refreshed and my angular code has control. Not the best solution this though, however.